# IIS URL Rewrite - match pattern

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the path `folder1/folder2/folder3...`
to d

```
efault.aspx?id=folder1/folder2/folder3
(default.aspx?id={R:1}/")
```

I currently have the following pattern: `^([^/]+/?[^/]+/?[^/]+/?[^/]+)/$` which works ok with a 4-level deep folder structure. However, since the number of folders should vary, I'm wondering if there is a pattern that does not limit me to 'hardcode' to a number of folders in the URL.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't exactly what you are looking for, but based on your example will work...

```
<rule name="ExampleRule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.+$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/default.aspx?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```